# Why video is not displayed in angular lightbox? Images work but videos don't

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I used the angular-bootstrap-lightbox to display pictures, videos, and other links in lightbox but videos don't work. Instead of displaying video, a text "Watch Video" appears and when click on it, it takes me to the link. Here is a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/g0jSl3WW36jGMYf3VNgz?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo1">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/0.12.0/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/0.12.0/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-bootstrap-lightbox.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="gallery gallery1" ng-controller="GalleryCtrl">
      <li ng-repeat="image in tiles">
        <a ng-click="Lightbox.openModal(tiles, $index)">
          <p  ng-src="{{image.url}}">{{image.title}}</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('demo1', ['bootstrapLightbox']);

app.controller('GalleryCtrl', function ($scope, Lightbox) {

       var images = {
            name: "User 1",
            tiles: [{
                    'url': 'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7300/12807911134_ff56d1fb3b_b.jpg',
                    'thumbUrl': 'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7300/12807911134_ff56d1fb3b_s.jpg',
                    'title': "An Image"
                },
                {
                    'type': 'video',
                    'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfq3OC6B-CU',
                'thumbUrl': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfq3OC6B-CU',
                    'title': 'A Video'
                },
                {
                    'url': 'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7300/12807911134_ff56d1fb3b_b.jpg',
                    'thumbUrl': 'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7300/12807911134_ff56d1fb3b_s.jpg',
                    'title': ' An Image'
                },
                {
                    'type': 'video',
                    'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfq3OC6B-CU',
                    'thumbUrl': 'https://farm1.staticflickr.com/400/20228789791_52fb84917f_s.jpg',
                    'caption': 'The left and right arrow keys are binded for navigation. The escape key for closing the modal is binded by AngularUI Bootstrap.',
                'title': 'A Video'
                }

            ]}

    $scope.tiles = images.tiles;

    $scope.Lightbox = Lightbox;

});
```

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: You're not embedding the video; you're just linking to it.

Comment: @ChrisStanley -- Still not working. I changed the link in the plunker to embeded video but no luck.

Comment: The link is just that:  a link.  When you click on it, it will go to that url.  What I'm saying is that you have to embed the video.  As in, you cannot create a link to it, or it will just navigate to the video.  You need to utilize the youtube embedding, which utilizes an iframe to show the video on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the embedded url, then it works

```
'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nfq3OC6B-CU'
```

instead of

```
'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfq3OC6B-CU'
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I updated the plunker as you said. I left one link embeded and one link with "watch?v" keyword but still doesn't work. By the way in Angular demos, it is also used links with 'watch?v'. Cannot understand what I do wrong

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes easy solvable:

- Controller module is for demo5 and your app is demo1.
- As exposed in the [angular-bootstrap-lightbox](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox) Github, if you want to embed videos, you need to use the [ng-videosharing-embed](https://github.com/erost/ng-videosharing-embed) script.